# Prove Standard deviation greater than or equal to Mean deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Ho do we prove that the standard deviation is greater than or equal to the mean deviation about the arithmetic mean ?

> $$
> \sqrt\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n}\geq\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-\bar{x}|}{n}
> $$

and under what conditions we get the equality ?

I think i understand that it is because of the squaring in standard deviation which tends to give more weightage to the data far from the central tendency.

Comment: The Cauchy–Schwarz inequality will do.

Comment: @Chappers could u help me how to proceed. i'm unable to find where to start inorder to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cauchy Schwarz inequality

> $$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^2\bigg).\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^2\bigg)\ge \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\bigg)^2
> $$

taking $a_i=|x_i-\bar{x}|$ and $b_i=1/n$,

$$
\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-\bar{x}|^2\bigg).\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\tfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg)\ge \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-\bar{x}|.\tfrac{1}{n}\bigg)^2\\
\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2\bigg).\bigg(n.\tfrac{1}{n^2}\bigg)\ge \bigg(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-\bar{x}|}{{n}}\bigg)^2\\
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n}\ge \bigg(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-\bar{x}|}{n}\bigg)^2\\
\sqrt\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{n}\ge\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-\bar{x}|}{n}\\
S.D\ge M.D
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $v=\left|\vec{x} - \bar{x}\vec{1}\right|$, where $|\cdot|$ is component-wise.
Then:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n^2}\left( \sum_i |x_i - \bar{x}| \right)^2
&= \frac{ \left(v\cdot\vec{1}\right)^2}{n^2}\\
&\leq \frac{(\vec{1}\cdot\vec{1})(v\cdot v)}{n^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_i|x_i - \bar{x}|^2
\end{align}
where we used the [CS inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) for the second step. 
Now take the root of the first and last terms:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_i|x_i - \bar{x}|^2\;} \,\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_i |x_i - \bar{x}|
$$

Comment: How does $\left|\vec{x} - \bar{x}\vec{1}\right|= \sum_i \left|x_i - \bar{x} \right|$ ?